# Sed replacing last comma fails

Tags: sed

I'm working on a sed script that takes a bunch of lines and turns them into an argument list for matlab (single quoted, comma separated).

It's working well so far:

```
[script to generate list] | sed -n "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#p#" | tr '\n' ' '
```

But this leaves me with a trailing comma.

By testing, I can remove it with

```
[list of comma separated values] | sed -n 's#,$##p#'
```

but, when putting it all together:

```
[script to generate list] | sed -n "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#;s#,$##p#" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Outputs nothing.

I feel like it has something to do with not having a p in the first line of the sed script, but I don't want it to print those values, I want them sent to the next line in the script (isn't that the default?)

Edit:
`[script to generate list]` Outputs a list of directories, for example:

```
./work/matlab_stun_gun/tex/fullTest.pdf
./Downloads/Howfar(tetra2) fixed.pdf
./work/savdocs/win_tests/tex/texReport.pdf
./Downloads/AcademicAudit.pdf
./work/matlab_stun_gun/report.pdf
./Downloads/PMB_4DVMC.pdf
./work/savdocs/win_tests/tex/mouseHeatMap.pdf
./Downloads/Geometry.pdf
./work/savdocs/win_tests/tex/mouseHeatMap.pdf
./work/matlab_stun_gun/tex/fullTest.pdf
```

The list generator is just `find . -name "*.pdf" | pickl -n 10`, adjusted for file type/ number etc. This is going to become a general purpose script.

Expected output would be :

```
'./work/savdocs/win_tests/tex/mClickss.pdf', './Downloads/Howfar(tetra2) fixed.pdf', './Downloads/MedPhys_defDOSXYZ.pdf', './Downloads/MedPhys_defDOSXYZ.pdf', './report.pdf', './work/savdocs/win_tests/tex/cSwitchs.pdf', './tex/zoomIn.pdf', './tex/fullTest.pdf', './temp/tex/zoomIn.pdf', './tex/zoomIn.pdf'
```

(Note the lack of trailing comma)

Comment: Why you have parens after `tr` command?

Comment: That was a copy error - the whole thing is inside `$()`. Edited

Comment: add expected output for clarity..

Comment: You forgot to fix the second one.

Comment: Your input does not match the output :)

Comment: Yes, `pickl` picks 10 lines at random, so the output is from a second run of the full script (after manually removing the trailing comma). The space after the comma comes from `tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: @BrydonGibson. My bad. I just realized where the space comes from too. That's your problem then. It's a trailing `', $'`, not just `',$'`

Comment: Also, the second `sed` expression should go after the `tr`, not before if you only want to clean up the one comma at the end.

Comment: Good catch - there's a space after the trailing comma. Putting the sed after and compensating for the space worked. Do you want to post an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Also, the real issue is that when you combine the two sed expressions, you leave out the /p/ from the first one, which is why you don't print.

Comment: Woudn't that output it to the screen? Or does the p send to the next line in the script (if there is one)?

Comment: try `sed 's/.*/\x27&\x27,/' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/, $/\n/'` ...with `GNU sed` you can do in single shot (assuming no NUL characters in input) `sed -zE 's/([^\n]+)\n/\x27\1\x27, /g; s/, $/\n/'` or using perl you can do `perl -0777 -pe 's/([^\n]+)\n/\047$1\047, /g; s/, $/\n/'` ... assumes your input is small enough to fit memory

Comment: @BrydonGibson. sed has no concept of screen, just stdout. Using multiple expressions is more efficient than, but equivalent to piping sed into itself. Really, you have no need for `-n` in the first place.

Comment: I'll draft an answer with all the stuff we discussed in a minute

Comment: I've updated my answer with some simplifications you can make to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a multi-faceted problem here, in the sense that each of your attempts has something wrong with it.

Starting with `[list of comma separated values] | sed -n 's#,$##p#'`, keep in mind that `tr` effectively makes your separator `', '` (comma-space)  instead of just `','` comma. This means that you will output nothing from the second `sed` expression. You can fix that by matching with `sed -n 's#, $##p#'`. If you insist on using the `-n` flag, that is the correct solution. In full:

```
[script to generate list] | \
        sed -n "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#p#" | \
        tr '\n' ' ' | \
        sed -n 's#, $##p#'
```

The problem with your combination attempt, `[script to generate list] | sed -n "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#;s#,$##p#" | tr '\n' ' '`, is that you need to apply `tr` *before* you remove the trailing commas. Even if this were to print anything, you would be adding a comma, stripping it off immediately on each line, and then replacing newlines with spaces. The correct order is already shown above.

Multiple commands in `sed` should be specified using the `-e` flag. They pipe the result of one command into another, equivalently to using pipes, but much more efficiently. To get `sed -n "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#;s#,$##p#"` to print, rephrase it like:

```
sed -n -e "s#\(.*$\)#'\1',#" -e "s#, $##p#"
```

This is of course going to strip off the commas as soon as you add them to each line, but it shows the correct syntax for doing so.

#### Further Improvements

You probably don't need to use the `-n` flag for `sed` (and consequently) the `/p/` flag for the `s` command. The `-n` flag is only useful if you only want to print matches, but you want to print everything, so it does not apply to you.

You also don't need an explicit capture group since you can use the `\0` replacement to get the entire match, not just the group. Here is an example:

```
[script to generate list] | sed "s/.*/'\0'" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/, $//'
```

Finally, there are alternatives to removing the trailing bits of the string without starting a subprocess, especially since you are already enclosing your expression in `$(...)`:

```
RESULT=$([script to generate list] | sed "s/.*/'\0'" | tr '\n' ' ')
RESULT=${RESULT%, }
```

OR

```
RESULT=${RESULT::-2}
```